# Should I use an ANOVA or Chi square: I want to see if there is a difference among number of road crossings across different road types

Tags: anova, chi-squared-test

I am currently looking at the number of road crossings made by a taxa within a certain area. This area has different road types.  Road type A takes up the majority of the roads in the area and Road type D has only 1 road within the area. So if I had to look at the total road crossings per road type it is skewed (e.g. 100km for Road type A vs. 1km for Road type D); and because of this I wanted to take the length of the road types into account. So far I have split my data up into two ways (the first made sense to me initially, but then I began to second guess this) and am getting very different results in R. I have given a short example of my set up below for each method:

[image: short example of data]

I assume that if there is an interaction between road length and road type I should be getting the same result as the chi square test but I am not. Please forgive my naive understanding of stats. I simply want to answer the question: Is there a difference between the number of road crossings across the road types (while accounting for the fact that there are more roads in one type compared to another)?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither is appropriate!

1. The usual ANOVA assumptions include constant variance (among other things). This assumption won't generally be satisfied by count data with varying mean. In addition, with small expected counts you will have a very skewed, discrete distribution that won't be anywhere close to normal.
2. A chi-squared test should be performed on counts, not scaled counts -- the variance will be wrong if you scale it like that.

   To adjust for an exposure variable (like road length) you don't divide by it, you use an offset (of log-exposure) with a log link in a GLM. This could be reasonable with a Poisson or a negative binomial response for example.

Comment: Thank you so much Glen_b. I've run the model which looked something like:                                     model1<-glm(crossings~roadtype+offset(log(roadlength)), family poisson)                                                                                                                                and the p values from the summary are <0.05 except for road type E. Am I correcting in understanding that this means each road type influences the number of crossings except for road type E?  I'm sorry if this is a trivial question, but anything above standard stats is quite foreign to me.

Comment: I think it should be `family=poisson`  there. The coefficient for road type E being insignificant would say that road type E is not significantly different from the baseline (which should be road type A) but the others are (at the 5% level ... be careful of multiple comparisons there); that two road types didn't have significantly different means doesn't alter the conclusion that road type affects crossings; unless there was a specific desire to compare to road type A that's probably not what you want to look at. ...ctd

Comment: ctd... Perhaps more typically you'd compare models with and without road type and show that the change in deviance was significant (using an asymptotic chi-square test)